# Extracting value from $scope variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

How can I assign a regular javascript variable to the current value of an angular $scope variable without binding their values?

```
//$scope.var1 is initialized to some value, say 5
var v2 = $scope.var1;
//$scope.var1 is changed to 7
```

I want `v2` to still be 5, not 7.

Comment: `var v2 = angular.copy($scope.var1)`

Comment: What's the context where you're changing the $scope.var1? You may need to wait for the digest to run depending on when you reference the $scope.var1.

Comment: _v2 will just be 5 only_. Since you are copying only the primitive not any reference (even if $scope.var1 holds a reference you wont see the change reflected in v2 if the entire reference held by $scope.var1 (unless you change a property on $scope.var1) changes). @tymeJV you wont need that for this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
var v2 = angular.copy($scope.var1);
```